# Hibernate equals method

Tags: hibernate, orm

There're a lot of questions out there which are related to how implement a good equals and hashcode function of an Entity that is managed by Hibernate.
However, I didn't find any solution for my problem:

I'm having an entity class that doesn't have a business key. It has a generated primary key, some properties which cannot be used for identity and several associations to other entity classes. I always try to stick to Hibernate's recommendations (equality on business key(s)), so I don't want to check on the generated Id. 
This leads to checking on 2 associations which uniquely identify my entity class.
But this has the consequence that those 2 associations must be defined as FetchType.EAGER.

Are there any other alternatives which I can consider for my equals function?

**UPDATE:**

What do you think about following solution for a 'generic' equals method in Hibernate?

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) return true;
    if (! (object instanceof AbstractEntity)) return false;

    AbstractEntity other = (AbstractEntity) object;

    if (getId() == null && other.getId() != null) return false;
    if (getId() != null && other.getId() == null) return false;
    if (getId() == null && other.getId() == null) return uuid == other.uuid;
    return getId().longValue() == other.getId().longValue();
}
```

By this, the entity can safely used in Sets. When the entity is detached, it is compared by ID. When the entity is transient, it is compared by a generated UUID. So the only disadvantage I see is that transient entities are compared by UUID instead of a business key.

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Why can't you use the generated primary key?

Comment: When the entity is transient, the id is still null. Imagine that the entity is added the a java.util.Set and the session flushes the state to the database. Then the id will be assigned a value which causes a change of the hashcode. This breaks the contract.

Comment: @user2054927: this is actually a good question. I've never found a decent way, other than not defining equals at all. Using a business key also breaks the contract if it's not immutable. If you absolutely need equals(), you can use the ID to implement it, but prevent any addition to a Set if the ID is not set yet.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay does something similar to the below solution. I hope it helps.

This solution would require an additional column in your table and a field in your entity which would hold a unique "counter". This the counter that would make your entities unique.

There would be a new table, say "ENTITY_COUNTER" table, that would have two columns - 1. your entity name and 2. the highest "possible" counter given out.

You would need to create a singleton which would hand out these unique counters (think tokens) to your entities when they are created. The counter would be incremented by 1 every time an entity takes a token.

Your singleton would not go to the database every time to update the highest token. It would update the database every time it has given out say a 1000 unique tokens. The singleton would get a batch of 1000 tokens to give out and once it exhausts those tokens it would update the ENTITY_COUNTER table with the highest token number it holds.

For e.g. the first update in the ENTITY_COUNTER would be EntityName 1000 and that number would be incremented by a 1000 every time a 1000 entities have been created.

That way you can have a unique identifier that is available to your entity before it is persisted.